# How to migrate a ASP website from .net framework 1.1 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net

Im trying to migrate few applications from .net framework 1.1 to framework 4.0.

For web Application, i just use the conversion wizard to migrate.

But for Web sites, what is the procedure to migrate and recompile the website.
I dont have a solution a or projects, its a folder containing many asp pages. 
I opened like open -> websites -> selected the folder containing all the asp files in VS2010.

there is no web.config or global.asax. So how will i know whether it has been converted or not.

Also please tell me how to compile a website, i have build the folder containing all the asp pages. Is that it? where do the assemblies for the web sites located.

Im  really new to Website development and this is the first time im working with Web site projects.

So please some one help me on this. Please ask if you dint get the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Link to [Upgrade an ASP.NET Web Application to ASP.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd483478(v=vs.100).aspx).I hope this might be helped.further doubts please drop comment.

Comment: That was for Web Application. every website says about migration os web application only. 
 I dont have a solution. The link and all other links explains about migration of solutions.
But i need to migrate the web sites i.e a bundle of asp pages.